# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, rest

I am passing a data from front end to back end using the below function

```
 async componentDidMount(){
 let data = this.state.i
 const addFormData = await actions.addFormData(data).catch(e => console.log(e));
 console.log("this is i for actions");
 this.setState({rows: addFormData})
 }
```

The entered form data is stored in the below function variable called
`values`

```
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
        this.setState({
          i:values
        }, () => console.log(this.state.i))
      }
    });
  }
```

I am getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htsdM.png) 
Can I know where is the mistake. Since I am new to this back end  part of `react` where passing api

Comment: This means that `actions.addFormData(data)` is returning `undefined`. Can you share the code of this function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put it in a try catch block

try this:

```
async componentDidMount(){
 let data = this.state.i;
    try {
         const addFormData = await actions.addFormData(data);
         if(!addFormData ) return console.log("this is i for actions");
         this.setState({rows: addFormData})
    } catch(e) {
        return console.log(e);
    }
}
```